# Does Firebase still count version updates as first_open event?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics

I was wondering if first_open event still includes app updates. I have read that it has been counting previously but should be changed soon. However, I could not be sure that if it is changed and not counting app updates anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From documentation, **[first_open](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en)**:

> the first time a user launches an app after installing or
> re-installing it.
>
> This event is not triggered when a user downloads the app onto a
> device, but instead when he or she first uses it. To see raw download
> numbers, look in Google Play Developer Console or in iTunesConnect.

The last important distinction is that when existing users migrate to the new version of your app which includes Firebase, they will log a first_open event. And so, even though they are not new users, they log a first_open.

In other words, it gets triggered on an update, only if the previous version did not previously have Firebase.

Comment: You seem to base your answer on the documentation, but there is a lot of ambiguity in the way it was written. If your answer is only based on the documentation, I would qualify it as speculative.