# Is first_open being sent after app update

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, events, event-handling

As of today how is first_open event being handled on app update when the previous version of the app was using Firebase?

Is new first_open event sent on the first opening of the app after the update?

Comment: Can you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When existing users migrate to the new version of your app which includes Firebase and app update they will log as a first_open event. And so, even though they are not new users, they log as a first_open.

As per the [Documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=en&visit_id=638072855875441137-4042706625&rd=1),

> the first time a user launches an app after installing or reinstalling it

> This event is not triggered when a user downloads the app onto a device, but instead when he or she first uses it. To see raw download numbers, look in Google Play Developer Console or in iTunesConnect.

The first_open event triggers only once after app installation. It does not trigger again if the app is opened several times after the app is updated.

You can also check this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046627).